# CreatedAtRoute with Api Versioning

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have searched all the posts on the problem in question, but I have not found any acceptable answer to this problem.
I have a controller with Get and Post like this:

```
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion(StringResources.ApiV10)] //"1.0"
[Route(StringResources.RouteWithVersioning)] //"api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]"
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public ProductsController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(CreateProductResponse), StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict)]
    public ActionResult<CreateProductResponse> Create([FromBody]CreateProductRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            var oid = _mediator.Send(new CreateProdRequest
            {
                Name = request.Name
            });

            return CreatedAtRoute(StringResources.GetProduct, 
                new
                {
                    Oid = oid
                },
                new CreateProductResponse {Oid= oid});
        }
        catch (ProductException e) when(e.Errors.Select(err => err.Code).ToList().Contains("DuplicateProductName"))
        {
            return Conflict(ApiErrors.ProductAlreadyExist4091);
        }
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = StringResources.GetProduct)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public ActionResult<GetProductResponse> Get([FromQuery]GetProductRequest request)
    {
        var result = _mediator.Send(new GetRequest
        {
            Oid = request.Oid
        });

        if (result == null)
            return NotFound();

        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

But when I create a product and return `CreateAtRoute` I always get the exception:

> exception.System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the
> supplied values.

The class `GetProductRequest` contains only `Oid` properties.
I tried to use `CreateAtAction` too but the URI returned in the header is wrong (it doesn't contain the path `/api/v1/Products`).
The startup configuration for `middleware` is this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
     endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

And for services is:

```
services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
{
     options.ReportApiVersions = true;
     options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
     options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
});

services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
{
     options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
     options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
});
```

I believe that the problem is due to the fact that the API versioning is present in the path, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The route (`"api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]"`) needs a parameter named `version`, so pass the `ApiVersion` in to your action and send it along with the route values:

```cs
public ActionResult<CreateProductResponse> Create(
    [FromBody] CreateProductRequest request,
    ApiVersion version) // <-- Add this
{
    ⋮
    return CreatedAtRoute(
        StringResources.GetProduct, 
        new
        {
            Oid = oid,
            version = version.ToString() // <-- And this
        },
        new CreateProductResponse {Oid = oid});
}
```